# write list of list to xlsx and start at row number xx

Tags: python-3.x, list, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I  have lists within a list, which i want to write into an xlsx file. The tricky thing is that i want it to start writing at row number 9, because there is other stuff before.

the code i tried is below. it only returns a lot of '5' in the column ... 
i would be really thankful for some help.

```
list_thing= [['a','b',''], ['1','2','3']]

row_start = 9
for i, l in enumerate(list_thing):
    for j, col in enumerate(l):
        worksheet.write(row_start,i, j, col)
```

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `row_start + i` instead of `row_start,i`? Also row and com are zero indexes so you should start from 10 to get row 9.

Comment: [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html) "cannot read or modify an existing Excel file." you'd probably want to use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

Comment: Correction: start from 8 not 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are wanting append data to an existing Excel document, you may want to consider using [`openpyxl`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) as [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html) cannot modify an existing Excel file.
Here's how you might do it in `openpyxl`:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'Doc.xlsx')

ws = wb['Sheet1']

list_thing = [['a','b',''], ['1','2','3']]

row_start = 9

for row in range(len(list_thing)):
    for col in range(len(list_thing[row])):
        ws.cell(column=col+1, row=row_start, value="{0}".format(list_thing[row][col]))
    row_start+=1

wb.save('Doc.xlsx')
```